# Mapping with sanctuary over fantasy-land IO

Tags: sanctuary

I have a small code sample that works as I expected it to when using ramda, but my attempt to port this to sanctuary has failed.

```
const IO = require('fantasy-io');
const S = require('sanctuary');
const R = require('ramda');

const url = 'http://localhost:8010?param1=arg1&param2=arg2';

const io = IO.of(url);

// Works as expected:

const r = R.map(R.split('?'), io);
console.dir(r.unsafePerform());
// -> [ 'http://localhost:8010', 'param1=arg1&param2=arg2' ]

// Fails:    

const s = S.map (S.splitOn('?')) (io);
console.dir(s.unsafePerform());
```

The problem is that the ramda version works as expected but sanctuary version exits with this error, can somebody explain the cause of this.

```
TypeError: Invalid value
splitOn :: String -> String -> Array String
                      ^^^^^^
 1)  function() {
        return x;
     } :: Function, (a -> b)

 The value at position 1 is not a member of ‘String’.
```

Comment: `Could somebody explain the problem?` What is the problem? Please add problem details to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only a single version of fantasy-io was ever published:

```
$ npm view fantasy-io versions --json
[
  "0.0.1"
]
```

It targets a very old version of Fantasy Land, so does not support [prefixed method names](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#prefixed-method-names).

The project has been abandoned. I suggest looking for an alternative. I recommend [Fluture](https://github.com/fluture-js/Fluture), which is mature and well-maintained. It also works nicely with Sanctuary.